# after running nutch with hadoop error job failed: name=generate: null

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, nutch, nosql

first i installed hadoop on 2 nodes and was worked perfectly . after that i install nutch on the server with this configuration :
nutch-ste.xml :
[image]

but after executing this command :

```
bin/hadoop jar ~/Desktop/apache-nutch-2.2.1.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.crawler urls -depth 3 -topN 5
```

this error appears :
[image]
please help me . what should i do ?

**EDIT**

I think the main error is here . but i don't know what should i do to solve this error.
[image]

Comment: Can you check the Logs generated by the Job with JobID job_201407101450_0009 from your Hadoop Cluster JobTracker?

Comment: @donut when i try to open it i have error . i update my question . now error is in my question.